# How can I use "Variables" in php, which are created by "str_replace" and "array"also in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, replace

I use in my HTML Markups always Underlines, which are programmed with PHP and will replaced by strings. For example:

```
<title>__TITLE__</title>
```

So in this way I have just one template of HTML but my pages although have their own title names.

But in one case I have a problem. I also use JQuery and I have this case:

```
$("div").append("<p>__NAME__</p>");
```

In this case there is the text `"__NAME__"` on my Homepage, not e.g. "John".

Can someone help?

Comment: You append the text, *after* the PHP script ran.

Comment: You need to assign the PHP variables to JS variables, e.g. `var __NAME__ = <?php echo json_encode($name); ?>;`. Then you can use the variable `__NAME__` in JavaScript.

Comment: Is this jQuery code contained in yout HTML template, or is it in an external script? If it is the former - then where is your actual PHP code that does the replacing, show it.

Comment: I think you're mixing up javascript from php. Can you show the full source code here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a placeholder `div` for it in your HTML:

```
<div id="template1" style="display:none">__NAME__</div>
```

Then in your code, pick up the contents of that element (which will have been altered by PHP):

```
$("div").append($("<p>").html($("#template1").html()));
```